# how to read data from a DataTable that stored in application with select query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

im developing a search module for my website. in order to make it work faster, i want to store my `Product` table in `Application`. like this:

```
        DataLayer dl = new DataLayer();
        string CS = dl.dataLayerConnectionString;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(CS);

        string FetchSqlSyntax = "SELECT AllImages.ImgSrc, Product.FName, Product.EName, Product.PID FROM AllImages INNER JOIN Product ON AllImages.PID = Product.PID";

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand FetchCmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(FetchSqlSyntax , con);

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(FetchCmd);

        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Application["Product"] = dt;            
        }
```

now i want to select some data related to searched keywords from my Product table that stored in `Application` and display it in my `ProductGridView`.

After all is this a right method for increasing performance?

thank you and sorry for my bad english ;)

Comment: You can check my full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataTable table = (DataTable)Application["Product"];
```

After that you can do whatever you want with your table.I will advice you to use `Session`, not `Application`.

```
Session["ProductTable"] = dt;
```

> Application state is a data repository that is available to all
>   classes in an ASP.NET application. Application state is stored in
>   memory on the server and is faster than storing and retrieving
>   information in a database. Unlike session state, which is specific to
>   a single user session, application state applies to all users and
>   sessions. Therefore, application state is a useful place to store
>   small amounts of often-used data that does not change from one user to
>   another.

You can read this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf(v=vs.140).aspx). Read last sentence and choose what to use. In my practice I always use session.

**EDIT:**

About your question in comments:

First you should not take `Top 10` for search functionality. On open of the page or another place you should cache all elements. You will cache this query in `DataTable`. If you search only in `Top 10` the result be almost every time wrong.

```
SELECT 
   AllImages.ImgSrc, Product.FName, Product.EName, Product.PID 
FROM 
   AllImages 
INNER JOIN 
   Product ON AllImages.PID = Product.PID
```

After someone use the search functionality you will make check like this:

```
if(Application["Product"] != null)
{
    DataTable table = (DataTable)Application["Product"];
}
else
{
    //fetch from DataBase
}
```

After that you can use LINQ to select only the specific data by search words or `DataTable.Select` method

```
dt.Select("ename Like '%" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%'");
```

After that you are giving the DataTable to your grid as `DataSource` or other control which use it.

**BE AWARE:**

Caching of queries in memory is Trade of right data <-> performance. **Use this if you have only hard problems with performance and this is your last hope**.

**I'm giving you an example:**

If user goes to Product page and we cache 100 products in the memory, we will take only 100 items from Session/Application, but if another user comes and create 5 new products they will be not saved in the memory. You need to perform new fetching and saving in the memory for them. Solution for this is to clear memory cache on specific time period, for an example 10 minutes. **Also the cache data must be cleared on some point because you can full the memory of the server !**

This will guarantee that the new data will be put in the memory, but you will have same problem in this 10 minutes. **Because of that I told you that this type of caching is trade of between right data-> performance.**

Comment: Thank you. you right, but the problem is how can i fetch specific data  from a datatTable?

Comment: 'SELECT TOP (10) AllImages.ImgSrc, Product.FName, Product.EName, Product.PID FROM AllImages INNER JOIN Product ON AllImages.PID = Product.PID where (fname LIKE N'%" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%' or  ename LIKE N'%" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%') and (allimages.imgorder=1)' how can i select this query from datatable?

Comment: @MahdiHesari check my edit. I will add other things which you should be aware of.

Comment: thank you for your full answer. i have problem with 'dt.Select("ename Like '%" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%'");'
is it a correct syntax for filtering?

Comment: and for new fetch we can do it when admin inserts a new product. users can not do this.

Comment: @MahdiHesari you can do it whatever you want. This is your choice, this is solution specific. I can't give you right answer for that :)

Comment: 'if (Application["ProductTable"] != null){SearchTabDiv.Visible = true;     DataTable ProductTableDataTable = (DataTable)Application["ProductTable"];
                ProductTableDataTable.Select("((fname LIKE '%" + SearchTextBox.Text.ToString() + "%' or  ename LIKE '%" + SearchTextBox.Text.ToString() + "%') )");
                SearchRepeater.DataSource = ProductTableDataTable;
                SearchRepeater.DataBind();
            }'
the filters don't work is it some thing wrong? it just displayes all of the products

Comment: @MahdiHesari when you use Select you should store that in new DataTable object: DataTable table = dst.Tables[0].Select("IsActive=1").CopyToDataTable(); This is example with my code because code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: its worked. thank you. one another thing is how to apply select top (10) in filters?

Comment: Its DONE! :D
'.Take(10);'
Thank you very much. sorry for asking too many questions :)
Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

I think fetching all the data out of the database and then searching it in memory will not be good for performance, if you do the search in the database and bring the data back I think your performance will be a lot better.  Databases are optimised for this sort of thing and doing it in memory requires unnecessarily reading the data out of the database.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is not true. You can read the article which I point in my answer. Here is part of it *Application state is stored in memory on the server and is faster than storing and retrieving information in a database.*

Comment: thank you ned. But as "mybirhname" noticed, Application state is stored in memory on the server and is faster than storing and retrieving information in a database. do you consider another method for a better performance?

Comment: if you have all your data in memory and you don't have to query the database at all, that will be faster. But it isn't always possible

Comment: @NedStoyanov This is trade of like I wrote in my answer. You should save/clear the data in memory on specific time period !